# How to pass arguments to a function in a JS ES6 Class?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I am trying to create some ES6 classes to clear my javascript code. I am unsure about the way to pass arguments to functions inside a Class.

As I understood, the correct way is through the constructor but this would mean that they are bound once when I instanciate the class.

In the following example i'd like to pass an element `elem` to my function `Categories.addCategory`.

```
    class Categories {
        constructor(id, name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

        addCategory(elem) {
            $(elem).addClass('category');
        }
    }
```

```
Cat = new Categories(1, 'new products');
Cat.addCategory('#product1');
```

I also wonder if there is another way to pass arguments rather than only using the constructor.

Sorry if the question is unclear i'm fairly new to ES6 Classes and may have missed some core points.

Comment: let categories = new Categories(id, name);

categories.action(elem);

Comment: thanks for your answer, I just realized how dumb I was here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you already know how to create instances off of a class. Now you just need to invoke the method from the instance, passing arguments as values between the parens of the invocation.

```
const instanceOfCategories = new Categories('12345', 'John')

instanceOfCategories.action('.your-selector')
```

You can have more than one argument, and the order you pass them is the order they'll arrive in the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
let categories = new Categories();
categories.id = 5;
categories.name = "Books";
```